# Storing large Mongo Document using GridFs

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, gridfs, mongotemplate

I have large mongo db document that I want to store using GridFs library.

For small documents, we use MongoDbTemplate as:

```
DBObject dbObject =  new DbObject();
dbObject.put("user", "alex");

mongoDbTemplate.save(dbObject, "collectionName");
```

For large documents, we use GridFsTemplate as:

```
DBObject metaData = new BasicDBObject();
metaData.put("user", "alex");

InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/test.png"); 
gridFsTemplate.store(inputStream, "test.png", "image/png", metaData).toString();
```

Here's we don't define any collectionName. Is there any way to store large documents within a given collection?

Answer (score 0):

GridFS uses `files` and `chunks` collections. Their names are not configurable.

You can choose which database you store the data in.